# App Engine ndb query to JSON

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I'm looking to extract two properties through an ndb query and convert them into JSON.
This seems to work when I use `print response` as this will be the outcome:

```
[{"LogTime": "2015-09-13T13:26:44.225394Z", "Temp": 40}]
```

However, when I then use `self.response.out.write.response` it adds random characters to the start of the JSON file which means the JSON isn't valid.

```
)]}',
[{"LogTime": "2015-09-13T13:26:44.225394Z", "Temp": 40}]
```

I've added the bulk of my code below so hopefully any glaring mistakes can be spotted!

```
entities = OutsideTemp.query().order(-OutsideTemp.LogTime).fetch(1, projection=[OutsideTemp.Temp, OutsideTemp.LogTime])
for entity in entities:
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
    obj = {
            'LogTime': str(entity.LogTime),
            'Temp': entity.Temp
            } 

    response = obj

print response
self.response.out.write(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix you are seeing is being added by the framework you are using (in response.out.write) to implement the AngularJS json security vulnerability workaround (see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations)).

I am unsure of any python webapp framework that does this by default when writing responses; perhaps this has been added in by a colleague? Check the code for the 'response.out.write' method has not been overridden.

Comment: You're right. I was using the Google Scaffold here: https://github.com/google/gae-secure-scaffold-python and there is a prefix in the handlers.py Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not producing JSON at all. Use `json.dump()` to produce a JSON, having it write directly to the `self.response.out` object:

```
data = [{'LogTime': str(entity.LogTime), 'Temp': entity.Temp}
        for entity in entities]
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
json.dump(data, self.response.out)
```

The list comprehension builds up a list of dictionaries first.

Note that the headers need only to be set the once, not for each object in the list of entities.

Comment: Thanks for the response Martijn. I've updated to this in my code but it's still outputting `)]}',` on the first line of the JSON file. However, `print data` only shows the valid JSON in the logs

Comment: Something *else* is producing that. Comment out the `json.dump()` call and it'll still be there.

Comment: You could remove half your method and see if it still happens. Then remove the other half if it doesn't. Narrow it down to the part causing this.